# Automatic scroll onkeydown even though it's not necessary

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

As you can see in the gif below, I have a `textarea` with a hint below which shows the current amount of characters entered and the character limit. When the content on the page gets so tall that it requires scroll, I'm facing an issue with automatic scrolling to the textarea.

[image]

I would like the the hint below to be visible as the users are typing. However, as you can see in the gif, if I scroll down to make it visible, as soon as I start typing it automatically scrolls up back up. This happens even though the whole `textarea` is visible. The behavior would make sense if the `textarea` was no longer visible when I started typing, but not in this situation.

Here is the HTML:

```
<mat-form-field class="mat-text-area" *ngIf="isWritingQuestion" appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Spørgsmål</mat-label>
          <textarea matInput cdkTextareaAutosize cdkAutosizeMaxRows="10" #textArea></textarea>
          <mat-hint align="end"><span [style.color]="textArea.value.length > 300 ? 'red' : 'unset'">{{textArea.value.length}}</span> / 300</mat-hint>
 </mat-form-field>
```

If I remove `cdkTextareaAutosize` and `cdkAutosizeMaxRows="10"` from the `textarea`, this is no longer a problem. However, I would like to use the autosize feature, so I'm hoping there is a way to fix this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I fixed it. The `textarea` and the `component` it belongs to is inside a `main` element. I had to add a `margin-bottom` of a certain size to that `main` element (had to be `70px` or bigger. If it was smaller, the problem persisted). I have no idea why that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well on google chrome.

Looking at the [source code for cdkTextAreaAutosize](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/2f9a59a24c0464cbed7f54cbeb5cba73e6007715/src/cdk/text-field/autosize.ts#L232), it appears that there is a fix for firefox where some temporary bottom margin will be added to prevent weird scrolling:

```
element.style.marginBottom = `${element.clientHeight}px`;
```

This was still an issue on chrome however, but simply adding a fixed amount of bottom margin to my textarea element worked as a workaround.